# How can I open this smoke detector to change the battery?

Tags: smoke-detectors

I don't know the model of this smoke detector, but it's beeping from low battery and needs to be changed. I can't figure out how to open it, so hoping someone can help! Here are some photos of it:

[image: First photo]
[image: Second photo]
[image: Third photo]

If it helps, it's in Australia.

Thanks!

Comment: Things attempted: tried pushing, pulling, lifting the switch, sliding the switch - the switch won't move.

Comment: Have you tried twisting?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Yes

Comment: the latch must be stuck (3rd picture)

Comment: @jsotola any advice on how to un-stick it?

Comment: i see that you accepted an answer .... i assumed that you tried sliding the latch in the direction of the arrow ... silly me ... lol

Comment: This model appears to be on a hinge so i don’t think twisting will work. It seems obvious from the pictures that the latch with the arrow is meant to push counter clockwise and the main body will swing down on the hinge. Must be stuck, in which case get a bigger hammer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to have a hinge on one side and a locking tab opposite. Press it in the direction of the arrow until it moves, then swing the cover downward.

[Manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/918276/Omega-Exi-3786phm2.html)